# Laravel Postgres with laradock project

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker

so here is the error showing im running laravel postgress in laradock, docker

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function pg_catalog.extract(unknown, character varying) does not exist LINE 1: ...CHAR) where "login_details"."created_by" = $1 and extract(mo... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.